# Windows Store apps do not support WPF's <InkCanvas>

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, inkcanvas

I am working on an application which can take input thru touch screen using mouse or stylus.. Found that `<InkCanvas>` works really great for me, but Windows Store app project does not recognize/support `<InkCanvas>` tag.

Does any came across similar kind of requirement and scenario. 
Any suggestion.

Of course, one of them is  but it is not as flexible as `<InkCanvas>`

Comment: Might be worth noting that new Windows 10 Universal Apps support a new InkCanvas control, which has many improvements over the WPF one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [`InkManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager.aspx) class in WinRT instead of WPF's `InkCanvas`. I think you might need to use your own `Canvas` control with some `Shapes` ([`Polyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.polyline.aspx)?) and handle the Pointer~ events yourself, but I haven't done it myself so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Filip, I am trying to add InkManager into my Window 8 app project. What assembly you need to add for that?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you for guiding me in that direction.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh974457.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this control in xaml like: <ctrl:InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />
```

Don't forget to reference 'ctrl' like: xmlns:ctrl="using:MyAppNamespace"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Devices.Input;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Input;
using Windows.UI.Input.Inking;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{
public class InkCanvas : Canvas
{
    InkManager m_InkManager = new Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkManager();

    private uint m_PenId;
    private uint _touchID;
    private Point _previousContactPt;
    private Point currentContactPt;
    private double x1;
    private double y1;
    private double x2;
    private double y2;

    private Color m_CurrentDrawingColor = Colors.Black;
    private double m_CurrentDrawingSize = 4;

    public List<InkStroke> Strokes { get { return m_InkManager.GetStrokes().ToList(); } }

    public InkCanvas()
    {
        m_InkManager.Mode = Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkManipulationMode.Inking;
        SetDefaults(m_CurrentDrawingSize, m_CurrentDrawingColor);

        this.PointerPressed += new PointerEventHandler(OnCanvasPointerPressed);
        this.PointerMoved += new PointerEventHandler(OnCanvasPointerMoved);
        this.PointerReleased += new PointerEventHandler(OnCanvasPointerReleased);
        this.PointerExited += new PointerEventHandler(OnCanvasPointerReleased);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Children.Clear();

        var strokes = m_InkManager.GetStrokes();
        for (int i = 0; i < strokes.Count; i++)
            strokes[i].Selected = true;
        m_InkManager.DeleteSelected();
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> GetBytes()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[0];
        if (Strokes.Count > 0)
        {
            var tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg");
            var writeStream = await tempFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            await m_InkManager.SaveAsync(writeStream);
            await writeStream.FlushAsync();
            var reader = new DataReader(writeStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
            bytes = new byte[writeStream.Size];
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)writeStream.Size);
            reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
            reader.DetachStream();
            await tempFile.DeleteAsync();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapImage()
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(); 
        var bytes = await GetBytes();

        if (bytes.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                // For AsBuffer manually add [ using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime ];
                await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
                stream.Seek(0);
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    #region Pointer Event Handlers

    public void OnCanvasPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Pointer.PointerId == m_PenId)
        {
            Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);

            // Pass the pointer information to the InkManager. 
            m_InkManager.ProcessPointerUp(pt);
        }
        else if (e.Pointer.PointerId == _touchID)
        {
            // Process touch input 
        }

        _touchID = 0;
        m_PenId = 0;

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnCanvasPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Pointer.PointerId == m_PenId)
        {
            PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);

            // Render a red line on the canvas as the pointer moves.  
            // Distance() is an application-defined function that tests 
            // whether the pointer has moved far enough to justify  
            // drawing a new line. 
            currentContactPt = pt.Position;
            x1 = _previousContactPt.X;
            y1 = _previousContactPt.Y;
            x2 = currentContactPt.X;
            y2 = currentContactPt.Y;

            var color = m_CurrentDrawingColor;
            var size = m_CurrentDrawingSize;

            if (Distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) > 2.0)
            {
                Line line = new Line()
                {
                    X1 = x1,
                    Y1 = y1,
                    X2 = x2,
                    Y2 = y2,
                    StrokeThickness = size,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color)
                };


                _previousContactPt = currentContactPt;

                // Draw the line on the canvas by adding the Line object as 
                // a child of the Canvas object. 
                this.Children.Add(line);
            }

            // Pass the pointer information to the InkManager. 
            m_InkManager.ProcessPointerUpdate(pt);
        }

        else if (e.Pointer.PointerId == _touchID)
        {
            // Process touch input 
        }
    }

    private double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        double d = 0;
        d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2));
        return d;
    }

    public void OnCanvasPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get information about the pointer location. 
        PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
        _previousContactPt = pt.Position;

        // Accept input only from a pen or mouse with the left button pressed.  
        PointerDeviceType pointerDevType = e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType;
        if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Pen ||
                pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse &&
                pt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            // Pass the pointer information to the InkManager. 
            m_InkManager.ProcessPointerDown(pt);

            m_PenId = pt.PointerId;

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        else if (pointerDevType == PointerDeviceType.Touch)
        {
            // Process touch input 
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Mode Functions

    // Change the color and width in the default (used for new strokes) to the values
    // currently set in the current context.
    private void SetDefaults(double strokeSize, Color color)
    {
        var newDrawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
        newDrawingAttributes.Size = new Size(strokeSize, strokeSize);
        newDrawingAttributes.Color = color;
        newDrawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
        m_InkManager.SetDefaultDrawingAttributes(newDrawingAttributes);
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```